# MinGW-w64. Не работает элементарный алгоритм

Tags: c++, массивы, clion, инициализация, mingw-w64

Я читаю книгу "Олимпиадное программирование" Лааксонена и я попробовал предложенный в этой книге алгоритм перебора с возвратом для решения задачи о ферзях:

> *Вычислить количество способов расставить N ферзей на доске NxN так, чтобы никакие два не били друг друга*

Вот код для решения задачи:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, total = 0;
bool *col, *diag1, *diag2;

// в этой функции тот самый алгоритм перебора с возвратом
void search(int y){
    if (y == n){
        total++;
        return;
    }
    for (int x=0; x<n; x++){
        if (col[x] || diag1[x+y] || diag2[x-y+n-1]) continue;
        col[x] = diag1[x+y] = diag2[x-y+n-1] = 1;
        search(y+1);
        col[x] = diag1[x+y] = diag2[x-y+n-1] = 0;
    }
}

int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    cin >> n;
    col = new bool[n];
    diag1 = new bool[n+(n-1)];
    diag2 = new bool[n+(n-1)];
    search(0);
    cout << total << endl;
    delete[] col;
    delete[] diag1;
    delete[] diag2;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Я запускаю этот код в CLion, в качестве компилятора использую MinGW-w64 v. 6.1.0. При любом вводимом N всегда выводится число 0. Хотя для N=4 должно выводиться число 2, а для N=8 - число 92. Я попробовал также скомпилировать через консоль (g++ my_file.cpp) - результат тот же, выводится всегда 0.

Почему так происходит? Проблема в MinGW или в чем-то другом?

Я попробовал запустить код в онлайн-компиляторе - работает так как надо.
Путь к g++ в переменной PATH прописан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Намекаю:

```
col = new bool[n];
diag1 = new bool[n+(n-1)];
diag2 = new bool[n+(n-1)];
```

После того как вы просто *выделили*, но **не** *инициализировали* память - в ней мусор. Вы не можете утверждать, скажем, что `col[0]` равно `false`...

Советую инициализировать ваши массивы.